# Large File Recording in MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, file, out-of-memory

I would like to perform a recording of large files in MySQL using C#. I tried with the following code, but it writes in parts that have the size of the buffer. When I use a buffer with the size of the file I want to write, the memory that the program is using increases a lot, resulting in a 'System out of Memory' that kills my application. The code here writes to the database in several parts with the size of the buffer. I would like to write the entire file, not in parts. Below is the code used:

Sending code:

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

string source;

if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    source = fileDialog.FileName;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("To save a file, we need one first");
    return;
}

string destination = @"<file_path>";
string destinationFileName = Path.Combine(destination, "<file_name>");
int chunkSize = 7168 * 1024; // Arbitrary buffer size

using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(source))
{
    using (var destinationStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationFileName))
    {
        long fileSize = sourceStream.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await destinationStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            // Calculate progress
            double progress = (double)totalBytesRead / fileSize;

            // This method is the one that writes to the database
            //InsertFileIntoDatabase(connectionString, "Test", buffer);

            // Update ProgressBar
            lblGravado.Text = "Progress: " + ((int)(progress * 100)).ToString() + "%";
        }

        // Show completion message
        MessageBox.Show("Transfer completed!");
    }
}
```

Code that performs writing in MySQL:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    connection.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO files_table (file_name, file_content) VALUES (@name, @content)", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fileName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", fileContent);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    return;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

If you can help me with this problem, I would be grateful!

I would like you to solve this problem I am facing.

Comment: I don't see the relatuonship between the two pieces of code. How large are these large files?

Comment: i do wonder.. does `InsertFileIntoDatabase` actually writing the file in chunks or not.

Comment: You might want to read [Should binary files be stored in the database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/should-binary-files-be-stored-in-the-database)

Comment: What will you then do with the "large files"?  If they are images that will be displayed in a web page, it is better to have them in files and use `<img src=...>`.

Comment: Question: You might want to read Should binary files be stored in the database?
Answer: Yes! The binary code of the file


Question: I don't see the relatuonship between the two pieces of code. How large are these large files?

Answer: A 2GB file for example, This code is just an experiment with a database that I was trying to do (I'm still trying)


Question: i do wonder.. does InsertFileIntoDatabase actually writing the file in chunks or not.
Answer: Yes, I select the file and click send then the part corresponding to the buffer size will be sent

Comment: @RickJames
Question: What will you then do with the "large files"? If they are images that will be displayed in a web page, it is better to have them in files and use <img src=...>

Answer: It's just an experience that I want to test and learn from if a problem arises or any request I receive in any case

Comment: `BLOBs` for binary stuff, `TEXT` for character stuff.  For binary stuff, it may be tricky to get past the handoff from C# to MySQL, but perhaps that is your real question?

Comment: Is there any good reason to not have a COMMIT?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but how about another approach for this?
How about you only save the file information and the path of the files?
If you have tons of files but only a small database with file information
it is easier to handle backups and migrations will also be simple.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was doing an experiment with my database on my PC and I wanted to send the entire file, not just the reference.